# How can I use Pandas or Numpy to infer a datatype from a list of values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have an array of boolean values which is currently classed as an array of `object`. How can I get Pandas/Numpy to re-run the type inference engine?

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: b, dtype: object
```

The only solution I've found is to explicitly cast it to a Python array then back to a Pandas array:

```
ipdb> numpy.array(tmp)
array([True, False, True], dtype=object)
ipdb> numpy.array(list(tmp))
array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

But this feels very suboptimal.

---

A brief background on why this is happening:

- Data is being loaded from CSV files (potentially thousands of files which I don't control).
- Lots of them are poor-quality Excel-generated tables with blank rows.
- They are read with `read_csv`, and blank rows are dropped.
- But they're stuck with the wrong dtype, because originally that column contained blank strings.
- And I want the tightest possible bound on the data, as it's being submitted to a subsequent parse engine.

Comment: `object` is the correct `dtype` here though: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html they are really booleans so you needn't worry

Comment: I need to submit them to a data warehouse and to declare that this is a strictly boolean column. So I do need to get a tighter bound than "object" -- and this must be possible, because converting `pandas -> python -> pandas` changes the dtype.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, I get `bool` as the `dtype` when all elements are boolean

Comment: You can also forcibly cast the `dtype` `df['b'].astype(bool)`

Comment: To reproduce, execute: `pandas.Series([True,False,True,None]).dropna()`

Comment: Forcibly casting doesn't help. I need to _detect_ the type of the array after `dropna` has executed. What if they're integers, or floats?

Comment: You can do this: `pd.Series([True,False,True,None]).dropna().convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` or `pd.to_numeric(pd.Series([True,False,True,None]).dropna())` if you're on `0.17.0.`

Comment: Can you submit that as an answer so I can vote for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a mixed `dtype` initially even after calling `dropna` then you can coerce the dtype, seeing as all you're interested in is preserving numeric and bool types then calling [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) or [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) will correctly convert the `dtype`:

```
In [31]:
pd.Series([True,False,True,None]).dropna().convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

Out[31]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

In [30]:    
pd.to_numeric(pd.Series([True,False,True,None]).dropna())

Out[30]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```